# How to refresh a listview in fragment page : Android

Tags: android

Just i want to update my list view after deleting an item from fragment. I am able to delete from my sq lite database but its not updating to the list view

My code in Base Adapter, on Delete Button item.

holder.deleItem.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

```
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                AlertDialog.Builder helpBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                        mcontext);
                helpBuilder.setTitle("Are you sure..you want to delete?");
                helpBuilder.setNegativeButton("Yes",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int which) {
                                db = new DataBaseHandler(mcontext);
                                db.deleteItem(mylist.get(position)
                                        .get("id"));
                                System.out.println(mylist.get(position)
                                        .get("id")
                                        + "ID :::::::::::::::::::");

                                Toast.makeText(
                                        mcontext,
                                        "DELETED SUCCESSFULLY"
                                                + " "
                                                + mylist.get(position).get(
                                                        "itemName"),
                                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();




                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();




                            }
                        });

                helpBuilder.setNeutralButton("No",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int which) {
                                // Do nothing
                            }
                        });

                // Remember, create doesn't show the dialog
                AlertDialog helpDialog = helpBuilder.create();
                helpDialog.show();

            }

        });
```

Answer (score 1):

notifyDatasetChanged to your adapter.

Comment: should i keep notifyDatasetChanged in on click after deleting from database??

Comment: Yes, after deleting your db, but if you delete  your db from where the listview will fetch it records ?

Comment: Thank you for your reply Hussain, In oncreate I have set my adapter like this ,

 adapter = new AdminItemlistAdapter(getActivity(), list);
  listviewitmes.setAdapter(adapter);

In Adapter,after deleting my item, I have called notifydataSetchanged(), still not working.

Comment: adapter.notifyDatasetChanged(); whenever you want

Comment: I too used notifyDatasetChanged() in Activity,In fragments its not working

Comment: added my changes , I have tried using like this also mylist.remove(i);
notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: actually you are not removing item from list after deleting from your db, before adapter.notifyDatasetChanged(), do mylist.remove(position);

Comment: Your awesome  Murtaza Hussain, WOrking Thanks a lot :)

Comment: my reputations are less. After reaching i will accept & vote your answer

Answer (score 1):

if your `myList` holds the data for your BaseAdapter you need to remove your Item from this list, too. Not only from your database. Afterwards notify your Adapter, that your DataSet has changed and it will update by itself.

```
mylist.remove(i);
notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: Sorry i am not getting, should i keep this code in on click after deleting from database

Comment: Yes. Update your Adapter after the deletion.

Comment: thanks for u r reply Simulant, I have tried,  I have used notifyDataSetChanged(); & adapter. notifyDataSetChanged();  & mylist.remove(i);
notifyDataSetChanged(); still not wokrking.

Comment: glad to hear that. Pleas accept an answer so other users visiting your question can see that your problem is solved.

Comment: my reputations are less. After reaching i will accept & vote your answer

Answer (score 0):

```
helpBuilder.setNegativeButton("Yes",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                int which) {
                            db = new DataBaseHandler(mcontext);
                            db.deleteItem(mylist.get(position)
                                    .get("id"));
                            System.out.println(mylist.get(position)
                                    .get("id")
                                    + "ID :::::::::::::::::::");
```

> ```
>                                   notifyDataSetChanged();
> ```

```
                            Toast.makeText(
                                    mcontext,
                                    "DELETED SUCCESSFULLY"
                                            + " "
                                            + mylist.get(position).get(
                                                    "itemName"),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        }
                    });
```

Comment: Sorry Naveen , Its not working for me, I am using "DrawerLayout" Fragments. i have tried its not working

Comment: have u updated your arraylist that u pass in adapter like see seze of list post Activity or Fragment so i understahd

Comment: thanks for u r response Naveen , I have tried the above code ,  I have used notifyDataSetChanged(); & adapter. notifyDataSetChanged();  & mylist.remove(i);
notifyDataSetChanged(); still not wokrking